# How to create a model in Swift from different data-type Json array?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to create a `Codable` `Struct` in Swift based on the JSON I'm receiving.

The Json I have is:

```
{
        "data": [
        {
            "id": "a123b321c456xyz",
            "timeUsed": 12345678,
            "input": [
                [
                    "address_1a123b321c456xyz",
                    {
                        "getSomeString": "0123456789",
                        "getSomeObjectArray": []
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "address_2a123b321c456xyz",
                    {
                        "getSomeString": "0123456789",
                        "getSomeObjectArray": []
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "output": [
                [
                    "address_3a123b321c456xyz",
                    {
                        "getSomeString": "0123456789",
                        "getSomeObjectArray": []
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "address_4a123b321c456xyz",
                    {
                        "getSomeString": "0123456789",
                        "getSomeObjectArray": []
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "getSomeData": {
                "getSomeString": "0123456789",
                "getSomeObjectArray": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Models that I tried to use

```
struct RequestData: Codable {
    let data: [RequestMyData]
}

struct RequestMyData: Codable {
    let id: String
    let timeUsed: Int
    let input: [MixedData]
    let output: [MixedData]
    let getSomeData: GetSomeData
}

struct MixedData: Codable {
    //What should I do here?
}

struct GetSomeData: Codable {
    let getSomeString: String
    let getSomeObjectArray: [Object]
}
```

So, what confuses me is this part of JSON:

```
[
     "address_1a123b321c456xyz",
     {
         "getSomeString": "0123456789",
         "getSomeObjectArray": []
     }
],
```

If you need additional explanation, please comment below. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some truly strange json but it can be decoded :)

First change MixedData to

```
struct MixedData: Codable {
    let addressField: String
    let someData: GetSomeData
}
```

and then add a custom `init(from:)` to RequestMyData where we use an unkeyed container for the `input` and `output` arrays and when looping those arrays we create another unkeyed container to decode to the MixedData type

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    timeUsed = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .timeUsed)
    
    input = try Self.decodeMixedData(try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .input))
    output = try Self.decodeMixedData(try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .output))

    getSomeData = try container.decode(GetSomeData.self, forKey: .getSomeData)
}

private static func decodeMixedData(_ unkeyedContainer: UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> [MixedData] {
    var container = unkeyedContainer
    var result = [MixedData]()
    while !container.isAtEnd {
        var innerContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
        let mixed = MixedData(addressField: try innerContainer.decode(String.self),
                              someData: try innerContainer.decode(GetSomeData.self))
        result.append(mixed)
    }

    return result
}
```

Note that the property getSomeData is not an array.